# Python Scheduled Task Close taskeng.exe

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task which runs a Python script which makes sure I'm logged into a website when I unlock my computer.

Sometimes I need to use `getpass()` to get the password of the website being logged into (other times I'm already logged in so no need to get the password).

So when `getpass()` is used, a console window named `taskeng.exe` pops up.

The problem is, when my Python script finishes running, the console window doesn't close. How can I get that window to automatically close when the script has finished running?

As a bonus question: `taskeng.exe` currently pops up behind all the other windows. How can I make it so that it's the foremost window instead of at the very back, when a password is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting this at the end of my Python script appears to have worked:

```
from os import system
system('taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq taskeng.exe"')
```

I like it because it doesn't require any extra Python modules.

It could cause problems if more than one Scheduled Task is running at the time (I'm not sure if it'll kill all of them, or just one of them at random, but either of those could be potential problems to consider before just using this code in your own Scheduled Task.)

Comment: I wished this worked for me. When running a python script via. Task Scheduler on a Windows 2012 R2, this won't close the window.